# flutter - xcode11 - macOS catalina - cocoapod install error

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, xcode11, macos-catalina

Calling macOS experts...
Appreciate your help into looking at this issue on pod install on flutter-- details are here

```
command used
/usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose

   CocoaPods : 1.9.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.1.2
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.4 (19E266)
       Xcode : 11.4 (11E146)
         Git : git version 2.24.1 (Apple Git-126)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.4.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

ERROR

```
RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.15.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:227:in
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's happening with pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952743/whats-happening-with-pod)

Answer (score 1):

2 steps to fix..

gem install cocoapods --pre
gem install mygem --user-install

and voila. your problems for days is solved...

Answer (score 0):

What could help:

`gem install cocoapods --pre`

and maybe

`gem update`

If it doesn't help, check if your project format is correct:
[image]

Sources: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7697 
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7458

Comment: This one helped also, but my actual problem was the xcodeproject settings, which some of the dependencies cannot be found.